# Why are there red names in Quests?

Tags: toukiden-kiwami

I noticed that the fox picture means that you may meet your Tenko, but what about if the **mission name is colour red**? Does this mean that there might be a Mitama or rare spawned monsters?

Comment: i think they are Main Story Mission. . . .

Comment: There are more than one missions, including past missions, that have the colour red including extra missions (those that do not count as main missions).

Comment: oooh, that one. on PSP version i think red marked mission have some cutscene. After you beat them run around talk to everyone.